# Como transferir conteúdo de um div 'contenteditable' para uma textarea ou input?

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou com um problema ao tentar transferir conteúdo de um `DIV` editável para uma `textarea` com Jquery.

O código que estou usando é este aqui:

```
function setData(id) {
    id.className = "input editavel esse";
    var valor = $(".esse").text()
    $(".esse").next("td").children("textarea").text("\""+valor + "\"")
    $(".esse").removeClass("esse")
}
```

Esta função é chamada no `onchange` da `div` funciona perfeitamente quando troco o conteúdo da `div` ao digitar, porém quando o conteúdo vem dinamicamente do banco (Tabela HTML) a função substitui a `textarea` pelo conteúdo ao invés de colocar o mesmo dentro dela.

Answer (score 1):

O `.text("\""+valor + "\"")` é usado geralmente para manipular o DOM e não o valor do campo (não conheço o Core do jQuery profundamente), também não entendi as aspas aqui `"\""+valor + "\""`.

Para resumir, se você está pegando o texto usando `$(".esse").text()`, você não irá pegar richtext, irá pegar apenas texto puro.

Use `.val`, então tente usar desta maneira:

```
 function setData(id) {
        id.className = "input editavel esse";
        var valor = $(".esse").text()
        $(".esse").next("td").children("textarea").val(valor)
        $(".esse").removeClass("esse")
    }
```

Note que ao usar `.esse`, pegará todos elementos com está classe, acredito que o correto seria pegar pela `id` (acredito que este id seja um elemento html/dom), se este `setData(id)` for uma `string` ou `int`, isto está errado:

`id.className = "input editavel esse";`